# How to fix "java.lang.error" in java HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to log into a website with HtmlUnitDriver and I keep getting a java.lang.error.

Ive added multiple jars to fix my com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.browserversion error which fixed that but caused another problem.

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices;
public class selenium
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true); // line that shows a error
    String baseUrl = "website";

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get(baseUrl);

    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']")).click();
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    HtmlUnitDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    HtmlUnitDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Comment: The compiler is indicating that it can't find the class HTMLUnitDriver. Did you [download](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver) and install it? Did you include an import statement pointing to it?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I have downloaded it, but I dont think ive included an import statement pointing to it. Could you clarify what you mean by that if possible? Thanks for the answer aswell. (unless you mean import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;)

Comment: Post the top of the file from which you copied the code you included in your original post. I need to see everything above the first appearance of the words `public class` or `class`. Import statements are a very, very fundamental aspect of the Java language, so if you more or less don't understand Java programming, you need to be honest with me, otherwise, I'll end up talking over your head and we're not going to get anywhere.